# Follow up intent for NO INPUT not firing with dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a "book reading" action and I tried to add a follow up intent for my read intent to reprompt a user if there was no response.  Following the doc https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts - my webhook never gets called.

However, if I add the no input handler as a main intent, I do get this event!

Is this a bug or did I miss something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The no-input event is a little unusual, since it is handled differently internally compared to many other events. It would not surprise me if this difference requires it to be handled as a top-level Intent. You may also wish to just try setting the context in your book reading portion and having this as an input context for your no-input event.

*However*... this will also likely not do what you want it to do.

The no-input event will automatically terminate the conversation after three sequential events, even if you don't explicitly close the conversation.

The current way to handle this would be to use a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) after each portion you read. This would include a very short audio file. After the audio plays, your Action will be `actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS` event, which you can use to trigger the next portion to be read.

Comment: The exciting part is that my narrator uses SSML magic to narrate. So, if I understand what you are saying, I should play a soft "bing" (like some audio books) to denote that I'm moving on to the next page.  (Thanks - that was actually really useful.)

Comment: A soft "bing" or just a very short, empty, audio. Whatever works in your environment. Glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

No Input will be main intent as it can be reused by other intents. You may need to save bots response in a parameter in the context to check what the bot replied when handling the re-prompts from this generic No Input intent.